# Hibernate: Persist tree like structure

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a tree like structure in a `Collection`. I have ensured that all nodes in the collection do not make extraneous references and are topologically sorted such that the root node at the head of the collection and all leaves are near the end of it.

My primary abstract node class is something like this:

```java
@Entity
public abstract class Node {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long ID;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Node parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "root_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Node root;
}
```

I do not maintain children list, but each node points to its parent. The `root` reference is a convenience field to refer to the root node of the tree. For example, it will be easier for deleting entire trees. Now I have many descendants from Node such as `A`, `B` `C`, etc.

***The problem:***

When trying to persist the entire tree, I use the following code.

```java
    // Check for extraneous references, and sort them topologically.
    Session s = hibernate.openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    try {
        int i = 0;
        for (Node p: objects) {
            if (p.parent == null) {
                throw new IOException("Parent is `null`.");
            }
            s.persist(p);
            if (i % batchSize == 0) {
                s.flush();
                s.clear();
            }
            i++;
        }
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error(t.getMessage(), t);
        tx.rollback();
        throw new IOException(t);
    }
```

This method doesn't persist objects correctly. If the batch size is too small, I get a `PersistentObjectException` with a message:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.Node
```

If the batch size is at least as large as total number of objects I can persist, but `PARENT_ID` and `ROOT_ID` in database is all set to `null`. I am using H2 while testing. Note, class `A` is always the root node, all other objects can appear at any level below `A`. I tried `s.merge()`ing too but that didn't work either. I have implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` according to my business keys.

Is it a problem with my equals/hashCode method? Or is it the way I'm attempting to persist? I don't know what's wrong with my code. Somehow I feel this is a trivial error and that I'm overlooking fundamental aspect. Could someone please help me fix it? I tried reading through different blogs that talk about hierarchical representation using Hibernate, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `s.clear()`.

It is basically detaching the objects from the persistence context, which may be causing the exception `detached entity passed to persist`

Comment: Dear Gods! I asked this question 5+ years ago when I had a short work with Java/Hibernate when I was forced to model a graph as table. Removing `s.clear()`, did not have any effect. It only delayed the error. I don't work on Java any more - that was the first and last Java job I ever had. Thanks for the effort though. :)